# how to check rhel subscription rates on aws platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rhel

We have ec2 instance of rhel 8 free ware
but while installing any updates i am getting error of subscription manager.
wanted to check how we can see rates for rhel subscription on aws platform

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ and switch the OS as needed. Alternatively use the calculator https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/EC2

Comment: thank you for the help. it resolved my doubts